# React state updates only when component is re-rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, state

I'm trying to increment value of React state `setMoviesPage` by 1 each time `handleScroll()` is called.
The issue I'm facing is that the state `setMoviesPage` is updated only the component is re-rendered (by navigating to a different url and coming back).

This is my code:

```
  const [moviesPage, setMoviesPage] = useState(1);


  async function handleScroll() {
    if (window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop !== document.documentElement.offsetHeight) return;
    await setIsFetching(true);
    setMoviesPage(moviesPage + 1);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isFetching) return;
    fetchMovies(String(moviesPage))
    .then(prevState => updateMovies([...prevState]))
    .catch(() => updateMovies([]));
    
    setIsFetching(false);   
  }, [isFetching, setIsFetching, moviesPage, updateMovies]);
```

How to fix it? Thanks

Comment: is the problem calling `setMoviesPage()` automatically triggering re-render, right?

Comment: What is `await setIsFetching(true);` doing? is `isFetching` some other React state? If so, React state updates are asynchronously processed, you can't wait for them.

Comment: @sungryeol the way around, `moviesPage` value increments only when the component is re-rendered (by navigating to a different url and coming back)

Comment: @DrewReese yes, `isFetching` is another state that is needed to call useEffect() (is per my code snippet) since `isFetching` is the dependency of useEffect(). If I can wait until `setMoviesPage` or `isFetching` are processed, how can I increment the value of `moviesPage` each time the bottom of the page is reached (I want to implement infinite scroll)

Comment: So do you just need to increment `moviesPage` by one when fetching completes? Or, sure.... have an event handler that bumps the `moviesPage` value by one when the bottom of the page is hit?

Comment: I want to increment `moviesPage` each time the bottom of the page is hit. Maybe another problem is that `fetchMovies()` is not called correctly either - currently when the bottom is hit, previously shown movies (of page 1) are overwritten (by the ones of page 2) instead of concatenating the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

It seems that when fetching movies is complete you simply overwrite the existing state.

```
fetchMovies(String(moviesPage))
  .then(prevState => updateMovies([...prevState])) // <-- overwrite state
  .catch(() => updateMovies([]));
```

With function components and the `useState` hook, state updates are ***not*** merged in with existing state, you ***must*** manage this manually.

> **Note**
>
> Unlike the `setState` method found in class components, `useState`
> does not automatically merge update objects. You can replicate this
> behavior by combining the function updater form with object spread
> syntax:
>
> ```
> const [state, setState] = useState({});
> setState(prevState => {
>   // Object.assign would also work
>   return {...prevState, ...updatedValues};
> });
> ```

## Solution

Update the `moviesPage` value in the scroll handler

```
function handleScroll() {
  if (window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop !== document.documentElement.offsetHeight) return;
  setMoviesPage(moviesPage + 1);
}
```

Factor out the fetching logic into a utility function. Use a functional state update to update from the previous state, ***appending*** the new data to a ***new*** array reference. Move the resetting of the loading state ***into*** the Promise chain so it's correctly reset at the end of the chain, otherwise it would just cancel out the starting loading true update.

```
const fetchNextMoviesPage = (page) => {
  if (!isFetching) {
    setIsFetching(true); // <-- start loading
    fetchMovies(String(page))
      .then(nextPage => {
        updateMovies(movies => movies.concat(nextPage)); // <-- append next page
      })
      .catch(() => updateMovies([]))
      .finally(() => setIsFetching(false)); // <-- end loading
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  fetchNextMoviesPage(moviesPage); 
}, [moviesPage]);
```

Comment: Drew, your proposed solution is elegant indeed and I really appreciate your help. Actually, I have learnt several things reading your code! However, after implementing your solution the array of items is still being rewritten and `window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop !== document.documentElement.offsetHeight` is executed before it should.. I will try to implement infinite scroll using Intersection observer, hopefully I'll be successful!

Comment: @gufox Yeah, Using an Intersection Observer is the way to go to trigger a callback when an element comes into (*a threshold of*) a view. I suspect you'll have better luck/reliability with that. Cheers.

Comment: I've reimplemented infinite scroll using Intersection Observer and this solution seems more reliable indeed. Also, there was an additional mistake in App() component (so there was no way for you to notice that issue) - I used to call fetchMovies() for the first 20 elements there. Sorry for that and thank you for your help again!

Answer (score 1):

When first looked up your code, what I really want to tell you is your useEffect seems not on best practice used.

Here I modify it for you with better structure.

```
const fetchMovie = () => {
   setIsFetching(true)
   fetchMovies(String(moviesPage))
    .then(prevState => updateMovies([...prevState]))
    .catch(() => updateMovies([]));
   setIsFetching(false)
}

useEffect(() => {
   fetchMovie
}, [moviesPage]);
```

And please note that you only need add the dependencies array to useEffect all the value changed that will trigger your action inside it. Also sometimes linter can give you some false positive warning.

Hope this answer can help you solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've implemented the structure you've suggested and now my code is more organised. In case I get a linting warning saying that I need to add more dependencies to `useEffect()`, should I use `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`? However, the problem still persists